# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Tags: c#

Имеется код (Не мой)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Globalization;

namespace SpeechRecognition
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        static Label l;

        static void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result.Confidence > 0.7) l.Text = e.Result.Text;
        }   

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            l = label1;
          CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ru-ru");
          SpeechRecognitionEngine sre =
          new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci);
            sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);


            Choices numbers = new Choices();
            numbers.Add(new string[] { "один", "два", "три", "четыре", "пять" });


            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb.Culture = ci;
            gb.Append(numbers);


            Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
            sre.LoadGrammar(g);

            sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        }
    }
}
```

После компиляции выскакивает ошибка:
[image: Ошибка]
Помогите решить проблему

Comment: Для десктоп приложений нужно использовать `using System.Speech.Recognition`. А для серверного ПО используется `Microsoft.Speech.Recognition` из соответствующего SDK.

Comment: все верно сказано выше. в данном случае у вас не установлен Microsoft.Speech.dll. Это COM-компонент. его нужно устанавливать в реестр. что-то вроде: regsvr32.exe /i Microsoft.Speech.dll. А лучше установить ее через инсталятор.